# k-chain integral example

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I posted the question but I still want to ask, how to integral with k-form method?

Let $\phi : I^2 \to \Bbb R $ be defined by $$ \phi(u_1,u_2)=(u_1^2,u_1u_2,u_2^2)$$and $$\alpha = x_1dx_2+x_2dx_3+x_3dx_1$$

Calcute

(a)$\int_{\partial \phi}\alpha$

(b)$\int_\phi d\alpha$

Q:can I apply Stoke theorem? The results of the (a)(b) seems to be the same, but the process is not the same. But still I need a guide to calculate such problem

Q:Is it 1-form or 2-form I can't get

$\int_{\partial \phi}\alpha = \int_{I^2}\alpha(\phi(u_1,u_2))$ ?

then = $$\int_{I^2}u_1^2( \frac{\partial (u_1u_2)}{\partial u_1}du_1+\frac{\partial (u_1u_2)}{\partial u_2}du_2)+u_1u_2(\frac{\partial (u_2^2)}{\partial u_1}du_1+\frac{\partial (u_2^2)}{\partial u_2}du_2)+u_2^2(\frac{\partial (u_1^2)}{\partial u_1}du_1+\frac{\partial (u_1^2)}{\partial u_2}du_2)$$
=$$\int_0^1u_1^2u_2du_1+u_1^3du_2+2u_1u_2^2du_2+2u_1u_2^2du_1?$$

then?